# Devolver el producto mas costoso sin utilizar MAX, ORDER BY ni LIMIT

Tags: mysql

Lo que intente hacer es crear un procedimiento que retorne el producto mas costoso, sin hacer uso de MAX, ORDER BY ni LIMIT, pero cuando lo ejecuto en CALL se queda cargando sin hacer nada.

```
DROP PROCEDURE mostrar_producto_mas_caro;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE mostrar_producto_mas_caro(INOUT mayor double) 
BEGIN 
        DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 2; 
        DECLARE n INT; 
        DECLARE precio DOUBLE; 
    
        SET n = (SELECT COUNT(precio) FROM producto); 
        SET mayor = (SELECT precio FROM producto WHERE codigo = 1); 
        
        bucle: LOOP 
            
            IF (i < n) THEN 
                LEAVE bucle; 
            END IF; 
            
            SET precio = (SELECT precio FROM producto WHERE codigo = i);
            
            IF (precio > mayor) THEN 
                SET mayor = precio; 
            END IF; 
        
            SET  i = i + 1;
            
        END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

Comment: ¿Es un ejercicio?

Comment: Si, lo es. Devuelve el producto más caro que existe en la tabla producto sin hacer uso de MAX, ORDER BY ni LIMIT.

Comment: Podrías usar [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest), dándole como parámetro una lista con todos los valores a comparar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberias usar `i > n` como condicion para salir del bucle al acabarse los productos

```
IF (i > n) THEN  
            LEAVE bucle; 
END IF;
```

Esto solo funcionará si todos los productos tienen codigos numericos secuenciales desde 1 en adelante.

Comment: Me arroja un resultado NULL el procedimiento, ¿Qué pudo haber salido mal?

Comment: Puedes agregar ejemples de filas de datos, puede que no este encontrando registros con id 1 hasta N, ya que por lo menos deberia haber un precio al inicio en `SET mayor = (SELECT precio FROM producto WHERE codigo = 1);`